# Read SOAP UI Mock service properties

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I am trying to read a property of a mock service in the `Script Dispatcher`

[image: the property "contatore"]

[image: the script where i'm trying to read the property]

But I get always error

> No such property [..]

Reading the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html) and [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html)

Do you know how I can archive that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do in order to get the properties at `Mock Service`.

In the script editor, have the following code snippet:

```
//Assuming that you want integer value, otherwise ignore 'as Integer' in below statement
def contatoreValue = context.mockService.getPropertyValue('contatore') as Integer  
assert 1 == contatoreValue
```